# Codeigniter - Google maps help

Tags: php, google-maps, codeigniter, geolocation

I am hoping someone can help me on a website that I currently building I store the users postcdode, using google maps api I am wanting to find the city that postcode belongs too, is that at all possible.

I am currently working with the following library, however I do not think that has the functionality I need.

http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/05/07/codeigniter-gmaps-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the Geocoding service provided by the Google Maps API you can pass in a postcode (or indeed any address) and it will return all elements of the location, including street, town, county and lat/long coordinates.

[Read more about it here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses)

Hope that helps.

PS. The library you are using is old and uses version 2 of the Google Maps API. Garry at In The Attic has since released a [new version](http://www.in-the-attic.co.uk/2010/08/02/codeigniter-google-maps-library-using-google-maps-api-version-3/), or I've got a version I built too [available here](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library) for use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm working on something similar. Here's a link to my project so far. This will eventually be the module that translates an address into lat/lng for a larger Code Igniter app that manages a data base of store locations. Does that help?

https://github.com/johnfmorton/Get-That-LatLng